# LDAP Authentication with Refinery CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, refinerycms, ldapconnection

I'm attempting to use `devise_ldap_authenticatable` with Refinery CMS. I've overriden Refinery's user model and changed its call to devise, and added in a devise initializer to configure it.

The path to my LDAP config is correct in the initizlier, but I don't think it's being utilized. I get a **Sorry, your login or password was incorrect.** error whether the config is there or not.

I'm not sure what else do at this point. I have a simple devise app with `devise_ldap_authenticatable` that I'm able to authenticate with. I just can't seem to get it work with the Refinery app.